# TarsosDSP Skip Function

Tags: android, audiotrack, tarsosdsp

I'm trying to implement a sort of a play/pause function on a recorded bit of Audio using TarsosDSP for Android.
Since it doesn't natively support it. I'm doing the following.
`OnPauseButtonPressed()` store the point in the stream with a variable
`timeWhenPaused = dispatcher.getSecondsProcessed()` and stop the dispatcher.
When the user presses play again `OnPlayButtonPressed()` `dispatcher.skip(timeWhenPaused)` and start the thread.

This works fine but the only issue is when I resume playback the dispatcher waits that many seconds in silence before resuming playback.
What I mean is, if I pause at the 10th second of the stream, When I resume playback, it takes 10 seconds of waiting before the playback continues playing which defeats the purpose of the pause and resume.

Is it possible to instantly skip to a particular point in the stream and how should I go about that ?
or is there a better way to implement the Play/Pause requirement.